# why doees my hover effect overlap

Tags: html, css

I have a image gallery with a hover effect but when hovering over the bottom of the image it selects the image below. I am not sure what I need to change to stop this happening all the images seem to do this, I have used a hover effect I found on the internet.

Is there anyway it can be changed, I have been trying for ages to make it work, I am using a Bootstrap to help build the website.

```css
*{
  font-family: Playfair display;
}


#wrapper {
  padding-left: 250px;
  transition: all 0.4s ease 0s;
}

#sidebar-wrapper {
  margin-left: -250px;
  left: 250px;
  width: 250px;
  background: #1B222D;
  position: fixed;
  height: 100%;
  overflow-y: auto;
  z-index: 1000;
  transition: all 0.4s ease 0s;
}

#page-content-wrapper {
  width: 100%;
}

.sidebar-nav {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  width: 250px;
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.sidebar-nav li {
  line-height: 60px;
  text-indent: 20px;
}

.sidebar-nav li a {
  color: #F2C8C3;
  display: block;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.sidebar-nav li a:hover {
  color: #fff;
  background: rgba(255,255,255,0.2);
  text-decoration: none;
}

.sidebar-nav li a:active,
.sidebar-nav li a:focus {
  text-decoration: none;
}

.sidebar-nav > .sidebar-brand {
  height: 65px;
  line-height: 60px;
  font-size: 18px;
}

.sidebar-nav > .sidebar-brand a {
  color: #F2C8C3;
  font-size: 25px;

}

.sidebar-nav > .sidebar-brand a:hover {
  color: #fff;
  background: none;
}

.content-header {
  height: 65px;
  line-height: 65px;
}

.content-header h1 {
  margin: 0;
  margin-left: 20px;
  line-height: 65px;
  display: inline-block;
}

#menu-toggle {
  display: none;
}

.inset {
  padding: 20px;
}

@media (max-width:767px) {

#wrapper {
  padding-left: 0;
}

#sidebar-wrapper {
  left: 0;
}

#wrapper.active {
  position: relative;
  left: 250px;
}

#wrapper.active #sidebar-wrapper {
  left: 250px;
  width: 250px;
  transition: all 0.4s ease 0s;
}

#menu-toggle {
  display: inline-block;
}

.inset {
  padding: 15px;
}

}







.gal {
  
  
  -webkit-column-count: 3; /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
    -moz-column-count: 3; /* Firefox */
    column-count: 3;
    
  
  } 
  .gal img{ width: 100%; padding: 7px 0;}
@media (max-width: 500px) {
    
    .gal {
  
  
  -webkit-column-count: 1; /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
    -moz-column-count: 1; /* Firefox */
    column-count: 1;
    
  
  }
    
  }




















.hovereffect {
width:100%;
height:100%;
float:left;
overflow:hidden;
position:relative;
text-align:center;
cursor:default;
}

.hovereffect .overlay {
width:100%;
height:100%;
position:absolute;
overflow:hidden;
top:0;
left:0;
opacity:0;
background-color:rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
-webkit-transition:all .4s ease-in-out;
transition:all .4s ease-in-out
}

.hovereffect img {
display:block;
position:relative;
-webkit-transition:all .4s linear;
transition:all .4s linear;
}

.hovereffect h2 {
text-transform:uppercase;
color:#fff;
text-align:center;
position:relative;
font-size:17px;
background:rgba(0,0,0,0.6);
-webkit-transform:translatey(-100px);
-ms-transform:translatey(-100px);
transform:translatey(-100px);
-webkit-transition:all .2s ease-in-out;
transition:all .2s ease-in-out;
padding:10px;
}

.hovereffect a.info {
text-decoration:none;
display:inline-block;
text-transform:uppercase;
color:#fff;
border:1px solid #fff;
background-color:transparent;
opacity:0;
filter:alpha(opacity=0);
-webkit-transition:all .2s ease-in-out;
transition:all .2s ease-in-out;
margin:50px 0 0;
padding:7px 14px;
}

.hovereffect a.info:hover {
box-shadow:0 0 5px #fff;
}

.hovereffect:hover img {
-ms-transform:scale(1.2);
-webkit-transform:scale(1.2);
transform:scale(1.2);
}

.hovereffect:hover .overlay {
opacity:1;
filter:alpha(opacity=100);
}

.hovereffect:hover h2,.hovereffect:hover a.info {
opacity:1;
filter:alpha(opacity=100);
-ms-transform:translatey(0);
-webkit-transform:translatey(0);
transform:translatey(0);
}

.hovereffect:hover a.info {
-webkit-transition-delay:.2s;
transition-delay:.2s;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="">

    <title>Starter Template for Bootstrap</title>

    <!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
    <link href="css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- Add custom CSS here -->
    <link href="css/simple-sidebar.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Playfair+Display" rel="stylesheet">


<link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" id="bootstrap-css">
<script src="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>


</head>

<body>

    <div id="wrapper">

        <!-- Sidebar -->
        <div id="sidebar-wrapper">
            <ul class="sidebar-nav">
                <li class="sidebar-brand"><a href="#">S.C Designs</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">Dashboard</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">Instagram</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">Overview</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">Events</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">About</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">Services</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">Contact</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>

        <!-- Page content -->
        <div id="page-content-wrapper">
            <div class="content-header">
                <h1>
                    <a id="menu-toggle" href="#" class="btn btn-default"><i class="icon-reorder"></i></a>
                    Simple Sidebar
                </h1>
            </div>
            <!-- Keep all page content within the page-content inset div! -->
            <div class="page-content inset">
                <div class="row">



<div class="container">



<div class="col-md-12">
<div class="row">
<hr>

    <div class="gal">







  <div class="col-md-13">
    <div class="hovereffect">
    <img src="https://preview.ibb.co/i0PmHk/1.jpg" class="img-fluid " alt="">
        <div class="overlay">
           <h2>Hover effect 1</h2>
           <a class="info" href="#">link here</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>


<div class="col-md-13">
    <div class="hovereffect">
        <img src="https://preview.ibb.co/mWpE3Q/2.jpg" alt="">
           <div class="overlay">
           <h2>Hover effect 1</h2>
           <a class="info" href="#">link here</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>





<div class="col-md-13">
    <div class="hovereffect">
            <img src="https://preview.ibb.co/i0PmHk/1.jpg" alt="">
                <div class="overlay">
           <h2>Hover effect 1</h2>
           <a class="info" href="#">link here</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>







            
            <img src="https://preview.ibb.co/mysOxk/3.jpg" alt="">
            
            


        
<div class="col-md-13">
    <div class="hovereffect">
            <img src="https://preview.ibb.co/i0PmHk/1.jpg" alt="">
                <div class="overlay">
           <h2>Hover effect 1</h2>
           <a class="info" href="#">link here</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>




                <img src="https://preview.ibb.co/mWpE3Q/2.jpg" alt="">
            





<div class="col-md-13">
    <div class="hovereffect">
            <img src="https://preview.ibb.co/i0PmHk/1.jpg" alt="">
                <div class="overlay">
           <h2>Hover effect 1</h2>
           <a class="info" href="#">link here</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>





<div class="col-md-13 ">
    <div class="hovereffect">
                            <img src="https://preview.ibb.co/mysOxk/3.jpg" alt="">

                <div class="overlay">
           <h2>Hover effect 1</h2>
           <a class="info" href="#">link here</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
            








            
<div class="col-md-13">
    <div class="hovereffect">
            <img src="https://preview.ibb.co/i0PmHk/1.jpg" alt="">
                <div class="overlay">
           <h2>Hover effect 1</h2>
           <a class="info" href="#">link here</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>




<div class="col-md-13">
    <div class="hovereffect">
            <img src="https://preview.ibb.co/i0PmHk/1.jpg" alt="">
                <div class="overlay">
           <h2>Hover effect 1</h2>
           <a class="info" href="#">link here</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>






<div class="col-md-13">
    <div class="hovereffect">
            <img src="https://preview.ibb.co/i0PmHk/1.jpg" alt="">
                <div class="overlay">
           <h2>Hover effect 1</h2>
           <a class="info" href="#">link here</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>







<div class="col-md-13">
    <div class="hovereffect">
            <img src="https://preview.ibb.co/i0PmHk/1.jpg" alt="">
                <div class="overlay">
           <h2>Hover effect 1</h2>
           <a class="info" href="#">link here</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>




                
<div class="col-md-13">
    <div class="hovereffect">
            <img src="https://preview.ibb.co/i0PmHk/1.jpg" alt="">
                <div class="overlay">
           <h2>Hover effect 1</h2>
           <a class="info" href="#">link here</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>




                
<div class="col-md-13">
    <div class="hovereffect">
            <img src="https://preview.ibb.co/i0PmHk/1.jpg" alt="">
                <div class="overlay">
           <h2>Hover effect 1</h2>
           <a class="info" href="#">link here</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>                







<div class="col-md-13">
    <div class="hovereffect">
            <img src="https://preview.ibb.co/i0PmHk/1.jpg" alt="">
                <div class="overlay">
           <h2>Hover effect 1</h2>
           <a class="info" href="#">link here</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>                





                    <img src="https://preview.ibb.co/mysOxk/3.jpg" alt="">
            
                







                        <img src="https://preview.ibb.co/mysOxk/3.jpg" alt="">
            



            


<div class="col-md-13">
    <div class="hovereffect">
            <img src="https://preview.ibb.co/i0PmHk/1.jpg" alt="">
                <div class="overlay">
           <h2>Hover effect 1</h2>
           <a class="info" href="#">link here</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>            







<div class="col-md-13">
    <div class="hovereffect">
            <img src="https://preview.ibb.co/i0PmHk/1.jpg" alt="">
                <div class="overlay">
           <h2>Hover effect 1</h2>
           <a class="info" href="#">link here</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>            







<div class="col-md-13">
    <div class="hovereffect">
            <img src="https://preview.ibb.co/i0PmHk/1.jpg" alt="">
                <div class="overlay">
           <h2>Hover effect 1</h2>
           <a class="info" href="#">link here</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>            






                <img src="https://preview.ibb.co/mWpE3Q/2.jpg" alt="">
                
    </div>
    
</div>
</div>
</div>













  <div class="footer-push"></div>
</section>
                    <div class="col-md-12">
                        <p class="lead">This simple sidebar template has a hint of JavaScript to make the template responsive. It also includes Font Awesome icon fonts.</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-6">
                        <p class="well">The template still uses the default Bootstrap rows and columns.</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-6">
                        <p class="well">But the full-width layout means that you wont be using containers.</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-4">
                        <p class="well">Three Column Example</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-4">
                        <p class="well">Three Column Example</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-4">
                        <p class="well">You get the idea! Do whatever you want in the page content area!</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>



    <!-- JavaScript -->
    <script src="js/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
    <script src="js/bootstrap.js"></script>

    <!-- Custom JavaScript for the Menu Toggle -->
    <script>
    $("#menu-toggle").click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $("#wrapper").toggleClass("active");
    });
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Change the margin on the overlay:

```
  margin: 10px 0 0;
```

[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/73rbdncf/7/)

Comment: It still is selecting the the image underneath

Comment: I just realised that in safari it works but not in chrome

Comment: Thank you yeah it works fine in safari, is there any way to make it work for chrome as well?